# PhpStorm gives warning when access to Auth::user()->id

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

First of all, I could access to `Auth::user()->id` when running the functions. But the IDE (PhpStorm) gives warnings like

```
"Field 'id' not found in \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Referenced field is not found in subject class.  
Note: Check is not performed on objects of type "stdClass" or derived."
```

But the `id` field does exists in the database table. How could I solve this issue in PhpStorm?

Comment: DO you use stuff like Laravel IDE Helper? https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper . P.S. It's all about typehints / correct PHPDoc.

Comment: just use `auth()->id()` :P

Comment: If you're only trying to grab the user id, no need to grab all the rest of their details. A simple Auth::id() will work here. From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication)

Comment: Thanks, `Auth::id()` will not introduce warnings in PhpStorm. However, I also want to access some self-defined table columns/fields like `Auth::user()->username`. Any further guidance? @UkraineInTheMembrane

Comment: For sure! If you want the rest of their information, I'd suggest just grabbing their details ( `$user = Auth::user();` ), then grabbing what you need. Ie, `$user->email`, or `$user->name`.